# Do we need to run `pod install` with React Native 0.60?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, native-module, react-native-native-module

I'm using React Native 0.60.5 and am linking [this module](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage). It says that for React Native 0.60+, "CLI autolink feature links the module while building the app", so all we need to run is `yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage`.

However, on the [main page describing autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) it says that we need to run:

`yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage
cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

**What I Want To Know:**

Do we have to run `pod install` for all native modules with React Native 0.60+?

Comment: After installing each native library that needs to link, you have to run `pod install` command.

Comment: I thought that `pod install` just linked the native module, and that that's what auto-linking was accomplishing automatically. What am I missing here?

Comment: Some will get auto-linked, others will add the dependency inside pod and you'll have to install em

Comment: @Auticcat So some native modules will get auto-linked, whereas others won't get auto-linked but will add a dependency in my Podfile, and I should do `pod install` to link them? If one of them gets auto-linked and then I try to manually link it with `pod install` as well, would that do nothing since it was already auto-linked?

Comment: Any react native library that uses a native iOS library will need `pod install`

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 types of linking in react-native

1 ) Manual linking

2 ) Pod linking

As described in official [site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

**"If your iOS project is using CocoaPods (contains Podfile) and linked library has "podspec file", then react-native link will link library using Podfile."**

Now when you

```
 react-native link
```

If you project has CocoaPods (contains Podfile) and linked library has podspec file then it will add pod path of linked library in podfile like this

```
pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path =>  '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
```

**But you still have to run pod install command**

If project does not have pod file or linked library does not have podspec file then you have to do manual linking as described in [site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

**Now coming to question from react-native 0.60 this process is now automatic. You do not have to run "react-native link " . It will automatically do pod work for you when you install library using npm/yarn but still you have to run "pod install" command**

Comment: When I do manual linking, I drag the `.xcodeproj` file to the Libraries folder, then drag the `.a` file from the `.xcodeproj` file to the "Link binary with libraries" section. Is this the 'linking' process that `pod install` does? In other words, if I manually link like this, is there any benefit to doing `pod install`?

Comment: I think the benefit of pod install is that you do not have to do any thing thing manually, Just run command and all done , on other hand you have to do all manual steps

Comment: So am I correct that all that `react-native link` does (pre-React Native 0.60) is add a line for the module to your Podfile, and then you have to do `pod install` yourself? In other words, with auto-linking, all it does is automatically add the line to your Podfile so you don't have to, but you still have to run `pod install`?
Second question, when I manually linked before, I dragged the `.xcodeproj` and `.a` files into their corresponding spots in XCode. Is that all that `pod install` does?

Comment: And last question (thanks for your patience), in the last year, I've never used `pod install`. I just ran `react-native link` and this successfully linked some modules, but not all. The ones that it didn't link, I linked manually. So it seems as though `react-native link` was doing more than just adding a line to my Podfile (which I never used); it was actually linking modules. Any idea what was happening there?
Thanks again!

Comment: Just to be sure: if I'm opting to use `pod install`, the pod linking will also take care of dependencies and linking on the Android side of things, is that correct?